# Rename uploaded image in numeric sequence (i + 1)

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a `json` post that uploads photos.  It works just fine.  I want to change the name of the uploaded file as it is uploaded.  I know how to do that.  I want to add a number to the end of the file name before the image type extension.  I know how to do that. I want the number to increment by one for each new file when I upload multiple images at once.  I cant do that :-(   Here is what Im working with:

```
if (!file_exists($vendimagepath) ) {
    mkdir($vendimagepath,0777,TRUE);         
}

$valid_extensions = array('gif', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');
$uploader = new FileUpload('uploadfile');
// Handle the upload
$result = $uploader->handleUpload($vendimagepath);

if (!$result) {
    exit(json_encode(array('success' => false, 'msg' => $uploader->getErrorMsg())));  
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
    $_SESSION['success']=true;
    $path = $uploader->getFileName();
    $vendimagepath= $vendimagepath.$path;
    $result = $db -> query("INSERT into vendimages (vendregid, vendimagepath)        VALUES ('$vendredig', '$path')");
    $result = $db -> update("UPDATE registervendors  SET  images='1'  WHERE    regid  = '$vendredig' AND username='$vendusername' ");
}
```

I inserted a variable under the if statement at the top $x=1; and then under the  $uploader=new fileupload I added a while loop with $x++; and put that closing brace at the end of the script.  It didnt work.  It uploaded files but they all end up with the same number (1) . I know why. The script is called for each new file uploaded so $x=1 restarts each time and therefore $x++ is 1 each time.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) instead of `file_exists()`

Comment: @Peter Probably not, since `mkdir` will fail if a file (or a directory) exists with that name. `file_exists` will catch both, since directories are just a type of file. The error handling if something already exists with that name could be better though.

Comment: OP, your code is also vulnerable to injection attacks. Using string interpolation or concatenation with queries is a bad idea except in rare cases, and only then if you really know what you're doing. You should use parameterized queries instead. Think about what might happen if I upload a file named `'); DROP TABLE registervendors; --`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to count across page loads, you should use your `$_SESSION`. Before the uploads start set:

```
$_SESSION['upload_index'] = 1;
```

Then do `$_SESSION['upload_index']++` each time you get a new uploaded file.